# Why is this specific question an exact duplicate of the one marked as?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

This is the duplicate question I am talking about: [Why this code does NOT represent multiple inheritance in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47899449/5779732)

This is the duplicate target question: [Why is Multiple Inheritance not allowed in Java or C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/995255/5779732)

In my understanding, this is not actually a duplicate. Duplicate target question is actually asking "Why is the feature not supported in the language". Whereas a duplicate question is asked out of misunderstanding.

Due to misunderstanding and confusion, a duplicate question incorrectly assumes that the feature is already supported *in one particular case*; then why is it not supported in other cases.

The OP of the duplicate question is well aware that the feature is not supported. But, he also learn that:

> Every type in .NET derives from `object`.

This causes a confusion for him and actually he is asking:

**If 'this' is true then why is 'that' not possible?**

In my humble opinion, this is not the duplicate of the one that is marked.

Note that the OP is not asking "why feature is not supported". He knows the feature is not supported, and he do not care why it is not supported. He is just stuck on one particular case that conflicts with this fact (as he thinks due to a misunderstanding) and he is asking clarification about the same.

I think, the basic problem here is the confusion of OP. It is not helpful to link him to the answers those explain why feature is not supported. It is necessary to clear his misunderstanding instead. This is not done in any of the target answers. No target answer explains that what he is thinking as "multiple inheritance" is actually a "multi-level inheritance".

Please note that I have edited the duplicate question to make it better. Please refer to the original revision just in case it is necessary.

Comment: @yivi: I read the target answers. All of them are talking very different. IMHO, those cannot clarify the miss-understanding of OP. Also note that OP is not asking "why feature is not supported". He know the feature is not supported and he do not care why it is not supported. He is just stuck on one particular case that conflicts with this fact and he is asking clarification about the same.

Comment: @yivi then consider the question to be "why not". A valid question IMHO, especially since "lacks minimal understanding" isn't a close reason anymore.

Comment: The problem is the question. In the title it asks " Is this the case of Multiple Inheritance in C#" (which I agree is not optimally answered by the duplicate). But in the text the only question asked is "When this is possible, why is this not" which is perfectly answered by "Why is Multiple Inheritance not allowed?"

Comment: @BDL: Please note that I have edited the duplicate question to make it better. Please refer original revision just in case necessary.

Comment: So the duplicate actually only conflicts with the title you edited in?

Comment: @BDL: IMO, the basic problem here is the confusion of OP. It is not helpful to link him to the answers those explain why feature is not supported. It is necessary to clear his miss-understanding instead. This is not done in any of the target answers. No target answer explains that what he is thinking as "multiple inheritance" is actually a "multi-level inheritance".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paraphrased question:

> Does this code represent multiple inheritance, or why not?

Is obviously not answered by the answers to the question:

> Why didn't the designers of Java and .NET include multiple inheritance?

The former is answered by:

> This is a simple misunderstanding. It's true that all types in .NET inherit from `System.Object`, *as long as they don't inherit from another type*.

This is a very, very different answer from:

> It would make the language too complex.

**If** the OP understood the latter, they would not have to ask the former. It therefore makes no sense to close the former as a duplicate of the latter, because it doesn't teach the OP anything new.

Comment: I think a lot about editing the duplicate question for better title. The one you mentioned in your answer is really far better than the one I choose.

Comment: Agreed. And thus I voted to reopen the question. To my surprise, I was the first one to do so, apparently.