# How should we call the assumed original of a question marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical, terminology

Some [expert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) has marked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53881650/476951) as duplicate of another question. In my eyes that is totally correct. I made a comment to the asker that I think he should go to the 'original' question.

What I want to know, how should I call this 'original question'? Since 'original' would be only true if the 'duplicate' would plagiarize the 'original' somehow, I think this is not an ideal name: 'original question'. Also 'original question' somehow conflict with 'OP' (Original Post) (which shouldn't be used any more, but is widely done so) and which would refer to the 'duplicate' in this case and not the 'original'.

So, 'original question' might confuse people, which question was meant.

---

To make things clear: What I'm searching for is a word or phrase that unmistakably tells anybody which question is meant. Especially for those which are not native English speakers.

But I don't want a word or phrase that assumes that the 'duplicate's' author only has copied the 'original' or that they didn't show enough effort to find a question like their own that has been answered.

---

A [thesaurus of 'original'](https://words.bighugelabs.com/original) gave me something like: pilot question, master question, archetype question. What do you think of these?

---

In [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360960/476951) it is called 'duplicate target question'. So it might be used in the open and agreed upon?

Comment: 'duplicate target'

Comment: intitial/earlier/primary?

Comment: The duplicate target doesn't need to come before or earlier, so any temporal reference is wrong.

Comment: If the 'original question' wouldn't exist before the dupe - how could it be referenced then?

Comment: @iLuvLogix I could be marked as duplicate long after. This is not that unusual. The more recent question could have better answers and the old question could have no answers or wrong/bad/outdated answers

Comment: They can be closed after the fact. Q1 is asked on day 1, Q2 asked on day 5; and later on Q1 closed as a duplicate of Q2. So Q2 is not either the "original" nor the "earlier" question. It is simply the duplicate target, or one of them.

Comment: @yivi thanx - now I got you why the temporal ref isn't so suitable in that case

Comment: "previous question" should fit 99% of the time.  If it doesn't then you probably shouldn't comment.

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of this meta post, but the message when choosing a question for closing as dupe is... "Similar questions frequently linked or suggested as **originals**:" Admittedly, I have never used that term and instead used "dupe target", perhaps from following many users using it...

Comment: "the link in yellow at the top" ? :)

Comment: I always say "dupe target", because I can't spell "dooplikat".

Comment: Not the case for this particular question, but if the linked question has lots of votes, I would call it the "canonical". Eg "Please go read the canonical for an answer to this question"

Comment: Although that's a good duplicate, the expert in this question could act more properly  in closing *regex* tagged questions (mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378107/vote-to-delete-good-questions-with-wrong-reasons)).

Comment: I thought OP stood for Original Poster, right?

Comment: OP does not normally mean "original post". It usually means "original poster".

Comment: ^^ OP can mean both of these. It depends on the context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question other questions are closed as duplicates of is typically referred to as the "**duplicate target**" or "**target duplicate**", from my experience. Other references may include "**destination question**" or simply the long form "**question this was marked a duplicate of**" (if you don't mind ending your phrases with prepositions).

Comment: Do you happen to have some examples?

Comment: @HerrSerker Sorry, examples of what?

Answer (score 4):

I usually call it the "target" or "duplicate target". I see some people have suggested this in the comments, so let me propose it as an answer.

That being said...

> Since 'original' would be only true if the 'duplicate' would plagiarize the 'original' somehow,

That's actually not true. Use of the word "original" does not imply that the duplicate question was plagiarized or copied; in fact, it doesn't have to imply any direct relationship between the questions at all. The word can be used in many different situations where there is an asymmetric relationship between two things such that one is subordinate to the other. So, to me, "original" is another perfectly reasonable way to refer to the target of a duplicate link. But if it would be confusing to a large number of non-native English speakers and "duplicate target" would be more clear, that's probably good reason to prefer the latter.

Comment: I'm a non native speaker (of German mother tongue). In German the word 'original' somewhat implies, if there is a duplicate, that the duplicator is kind of a copycat.

Answer (score 4):

The term **duplicate target** [of the closed post] is the easiest to understand, but we also use the term **[canonical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization) question** [on the particular topic], with the same meaning as in [canonical link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element).

Comment: I'd use 'canonical' only for stuff like the Null-Pointer dupe, i.e. a well-written target which has a lot of in-depth answers. Duping to a question with a single, not too great answer (which does answer the question of course), I would not call 'canonical', let alone when the target is one of the OPs own posts.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the most common term for that is "duplicate target". When addressing the OP of the duplicate question (for instance, in comments explaining why it is a duplicate), I tend to use "suggested question" instead, in order to minimise the amount of Meta jargon and emphasise the point of duplicate closure (and sometimes to [forestall automatic comment deletion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344519/2751851) as well).